# Explode string by one or more spaces and new lines

Tags: php, regex, explode

How can I explode a string by one or more spaces or tabs?

Example:

```
A      B      C 
D      E      F
G      H      I
J      K      L
M      N      O
```

I have successfully tokenize on spaces and tab's with this code:

```
$parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $str);
```

but the issue rises when there is new line.

I want to make this an array so that i can run mysqlquery as well.

Comment: what is the output you need?

Comment: Where is the problem ? What is your current output and what would you expect?

Comment: Can you give more details? So you have a string like `"A B\tC\nD"`, and you want to get array `"A", "B", "C", "D"`?

Comment: What is the problem with newline? Your current regexp splits by newline.

Comment: Your code work for me: `"A B\tC\nD"` is split properly.

Comment: @AmitJoki 
I want an array to be like this
Array a[0][0] => A
Array a[0][1] => B
Array a[0][3] => C
Array a[1][0] => D
Array a[1][1] => E
Array a[1][2] => F

Comment: @Petr

Here is code

$string = $_POST['all_data'];
/ Use tab and newline as tokenizing characters as well  /
$tok = strtok($string, "\t\n");

while ($tok !== false) {
    echo "Word=$tok<br />";

It tokenize properly the issue is in storing that data in two dimensional array...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a matrix of characters, split by newline first:

```
<?php
$str = "A B\tC\nD E\tF";
$parts = preg_split("/\n+/", $str);
foreach($parts as $key => $line)
{
    $parts[$key] = preg_split("/\s+/", $line);
}

//output
$n = count($parts);
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i)
{
    $m = count($parts[$i]);
    for ($j = 0; $j < $m; ++$j)
    {
        print $parts[$i][$j]." ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
A B C 
D E F
```

Comment: Where are you creating array?

Comment: @Bilal The 1-st array is created after calling the 1-st preg_split. The second - inside the loop.

Comment: Can you please display the array with loop instead of var_dump, I will be really thankful to you.